# Is there any chance to add @Facet field on existing index?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have 4 lucene index with Hibernate-search. Each has 2 million document. Recently I need to add @Facet fields. But whole index rebuild time is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to rebuild the index.

The process of rebuilding the index does indeed take some time, but with some tuning you can speed it up significantly.

Since there are many situations in which you'll need to rebuild the index, it's worth spending a bit of time to investigate on how to make it fast enough to be acceptable: you will need this also in case of disaster recovery.